# вопрос по PHP - массиву + замена

Tags: php, массивы

Доброго времени! Есть массив в движке

```
 $GLOBALS["_71720443_"]=array(
    855755 =>array(
        35=> "type_answer"
    )
);
```

и есть строка

`$text=' if ( $$GLOBALS["_71720443_"][855755][35] != 10 ) ';`

подскажите как в этой строке сделать замену значением массива, чтобы получить строку такого вида

`$text=' if ( $type_answer != 10 ) ';`

Comment: Если существует переменная $type_answer, то Вы просто можете написать $text=' if ( $type_answer != 10 ) '; и всё. Или я неправильно понимаю вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит что далее происходит с вашим движком.
Возможно так, если я правильно представляю что далее происходит в коде :

```
$type_answer=$GLOBALS["_71720443_"][855755][35];
$text=' if ( '.$type_answer.' != 10 ) ';
```